# NOPCommerce password protect forum so only some have access

Tags: nopcommerce

I'm trying to secure the Forum (boards) folder of the NOPCommerce 2.8 website. I would like to use the existing membership provider and roles that come with it. I just want the role group, "Forum Moderators" to be able view content in the forum and any other role group or anonymous user would be redirected to login page if they click on forum.

This used to be easy with .aspx pages where I would say ", and that would prevent anonymous users from accessing, but with .cshtml pages, it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a simple solution for using existing role security from nopcommerce to secure the Forum?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I secured the forum with the help of someone in the Nopcommerce forum

```
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Customers;
@using Nop.Services.Customers;
@using Nop.Core;
@{
bool customerHasRoleX = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.IsInCustomerRole("Administrators");
bool customerHasRoleY = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.IsInCustomerRole("ForumModerators");
}

@if ((customerHasRoleX == true) | (customerHasRoleY == true)) {

}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/login?ReturnUrl=%2fboards");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you understand ActionFilters, you can easily achieve the result by mean of a plugin. All you need to do is to check the role at the 'OnActionExecuting' method of your ActionFilters. If you search on nopCommerce.com forums, I've also written a few post to explain about this. :)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I did a search of all your posts and did not see anything on creating action filters for user authentication. Maybe I'm overlooking it?

Comment: There has got to be an easier way to authenticate in nop? It seems much easier in asp.net where I could just set the web.config to "allow roles". I dont' even know where to begin inserting an action filter. My nopcommerce does not have a controllers folder. or any other authentication.cs pages for me to work with. How do they do the authentication? And how can I access that? thanks for your help